# Multer didn't work for me not storing image in local folder or database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

What can I do to store files in a local folder or database?

```js
const multer = require('multer');
  let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: '/public/my-uploads',
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this file name instead of that if you are working on Windows OS, Your code is perfectly working on MAcOS

```
     filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(
          null,
          new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + "-" + file.originalname
        );
```

Hope it works for you...